# FrameworkElement не содержит определения для OnTransformDirty

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь зарегистрировать свойство зависимости

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushSizeProperty;
    static MainWindow()
    {
        BrushSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BrushSize",typeof(int),typeof(InkCanvas),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
// Значение свойства по умолчанию.
(int)1,
// Опции метаданных.
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
// Делегат, указывающий на свойство, вызываемое при изменении свойства.
new PropertyChangedCallback(FrameworkElement.OnTransformDirty))
);
     }
```

- на строке `new PropertyChangedCallback(FrameworkElement.OnTransformDirty))` -там где делегат PropertyChangedCallback - у меня не видит статический метод  OnTransformDirty(). Почему?

Comment: Может, его там и правда нет? :-)

Comment: Но ведь InkCanvas -для которого создается свойство наследуется от FrameworkElement

Comment: Это как-то должно помочь методу появиться?

Comment: ну если OnTransformDirty - это статически метод класса  FrameworkElement  - то да

Comment: А если нет?....

Comment: Метод `OnTransformDirty` является `private`.

Comment: и как мне в этом случае быть?

Comment: Вам нужно в некотором вашем классе создать целочисленное свойство зависимости `BrushSize`, я правильно понял?

Comment: Для какой цели вы указывали `FrameworkElement.OnTransformDirty` и почему у вас при регистрации свойства указан тип `InkCanvas`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас при указании обработчика, который будет срабатывать при изменении свойства зависимости `BrushSizeProperty` указан приватный метод `OnTransformDirty` класса `FrameworkElement`.

Посмотрите, для того что бы создать свойство зависимости, необходимо выполнить всего несколько действий.

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // 1 Создать обертку над свойством зависимостей.
    public int BrushSize
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)GetValue(BrushSizeProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BrushSizeProperty, value);
        }
    }

    // 2 Создать и зарегистрировать свойство зависимости.

    // При этом, во время регистрации свойства мы можем его сконфигурировать.
    // В данном примере:
    //     nameof(BrushSize) - имя свойства
    //     typeof(int) - тип свойства
    //     typeof(MyUserControl) - тип, в который владеет данным свойством
    //     FrameworkPropertyMetadata - один из наследников PropertyMetadata,
    //     позволяющий указать дополнительные настройки. В нашем случае мы
    //     указываем:
    //         значение по умолчанию 
    //         говорим свойство будет иметь двухстороннюю привязку
    //         а так же определяем обработчик, который будет срабатывать
    //         при изменении свойства
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushSizeProperty = 
                     DependencyProperty.Register(
                     nameof(BrushSize), 
                     typeof(int), 
                     typeof(MyUserControl), 
                     new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(int), 
                      FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                      BrushSizeChangedCallback));

    private static void BrushSizeChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {

    } 
}
```